# Simple formula using nesting giving parse error

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

```
=DAYS( =DATE(2019, 6, 27), =TODAY() )
```

Here I have a simple expression with nested functions that I can't seem to figure out. I keep getting a parse error. I've read the docs for all three of the involved functions but I cannot find an answer. Any suggestions to what I might be getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you combine them then you need only leading `=`. try like this:

```
=DAYS(DATE(2019, 6, 27), TODAY())
```